# How to mark with quotes every line in set?

Tags: vim

I have some text like this:

```
<datetime>2006-04-28T15:49</datetime>
                <surfaceintervalbeforedive>
                    30.00 
                </surfaceintervalbeforedive>
                <tankdata>
```

and I want to mark every line with quotes. Expectable result is:

```
"<datetime>2006-04-28T15:49</datetime>"
                    "<surfaceintervalbeforedive>"
                        "30.00"
                    "</surfaceintervalbeforedive>"
                    "<tankdata>"
```

I know that I can use **I-"** for first line and dot-command for every line. And after that **A-"** and dot-command. But there a lot of lines  and I believe there must be more "VIMable" approach.

**SOLVED**

I think the simplest approach is record a macros like @pktangyue said and apply it for range like this :1,4norm! @a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a macro.

Assume you're now at the first line

```
qa  //register a macro to a
I
"
<esc>
A
"
<esc>
j
q
4@a // here change 4 to the total line number minus 1 of your file
```

Comment: but I think will be better use it for range of lines. Like this:  :5,10norm! @a

Comment: @MaxKharandziuk you can jump to 5 with `5g`, then `5@a`.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a greedy match from non-whitespace to non-whitespace, like this:

```
:%s/\S.*\S/"&"/
```

Instead of `%`, you can specify any `[range]`, as usual.

Comment: @Fredrik: Thanks; though I'm no golfer, I saw yours and thought "there must be a better way" :-)

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to record what you do with one line and then use that macro with a number.
To record the commands to register a:

```
qaI"<Esc>A"<Esc>jq
```

Then you can repeat it with:

```
N@a
```

Where `N` is the number of lines you want to repeat it for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **I-"** and **A-" to mark a block of lines, just select the block first using Ctrl-Q (or Ctrl-V) and move the cursor to select what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `:normal` to execute a normal commands on each line. In the case below `I` to insert at the start of the line and `A` to append to the end.

```
:%norm I"^[A"
```

Where `^[` is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd>. See `:h i_ctrl-v` for more infomration about quoting. Depending on your platform <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd> for quoting my be available.

If you have Tim Pope's [surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin this becomes a bit shorter.

```
:%norm yss"
```

For more information see

```
:h :norm
:h I
:h A
:h i_ctrl-v
```

If you have surround installed see:

```
:h surround
:h yss
```